# How to remove a certain value if another value cleared? | AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a form where user select items and set quantity and and the price auto calculated with `ng-value= quantity*price`. My problem is that if user clear the item input field. the other values (**quantityu and price**) not removed programmatically.

My view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="sellAcc in sellAccessories">
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="sellAccessName{{$index}}"
               list="sellAllaccessories{{$index}}"
               ng-model="sellAccessories[0].name[$index]"
               ng-change="getItemSellingPrice($index); isExistItem($index)" >
        <datalist id="sellAllaccessories{{$index}}" >
            <option ng-repeat="access in allAccessories" data-item="{{access.id}}" value="{{access.name}}">
        </datalist>
    </td>

    <td colspan="1">
         <input type="number" ng-model="sellAccessories[0].quantity[$index]">
    </td>

    <td colspan="2" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="sellAccessories[0].total_price[$index]"
               ng-value="sellAccessories[0].total_price[$index]=sellAccessories[0].quantity[$index] * access_s_price[$index]"
               readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$scope.sellAccessories=[{"id": [],"name": [], "quantity": [],"total_price": []}];
```

i store all values in the array using `ng-model=sellAccess[0].name[$index]`, the problem is that if user removed the item name, what happens is `name` array will not be equal to the `quantity` and `total price`
.Assume that the user select 4 items and then remove an item that have quantity=4, then this what will happen:

```
name=["Nescafe","Pepsi","Tobacco"]`
quantity[1,4,2,5]`
```

while it should be:

```
name=["Nescafe","Pepsi","Tobacco"]`
quantity[1,2,5]`
```

many thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you using parallel arrays? That will be hard to maintain and keep track of. Use an array of objects: `$scope.sellAccessories = [{}, {}, {}, ...]`, so when you remove an item, you remove the entire object wich holds all the other related values.

Comment: Instead of using a read-only `<input>` element to compute the total, use double curly bracket `{{ }}` interpolation.